# Context in Spring MVC: how to declare bean into dispatcher-servlet.xml and get it in controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have trouble with the bean declaration in Spring Bean Configuration File.

I have a Spring MVC project, and I must declare bean.

The dispatcher-servlet.xml is in the folder WebContent -> WEB-INF.
The controller is in the folder Java Resources -> src -> com.controllers

How to create context object in controller?

I create:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
```

But it can not find it. So how to refer to him?

And the second question. Should beans should be inserted in a separate SBCF file or may be in a dispatcher-servlet?

Thank you very much for your replies :)

Comment: Try this: `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("**/dispatcher-servlet.xml");`

Comment: Repeat after me... Unless you are bootstrapping your application NEVER NEVER NEVER create an application context. Unless you want memory issues, weird transaction issues, database connectivity issues etc. Just inject the dependencies into the controller don't create a new context to retrieve them.

Comment: If `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is being loaded by `DispatcherServlet` then, it can be autowired using `@Autowired private WebApplicationContext context;` and can be used to get any bean defined in that context